# Test .NET6 minimal API with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, webapi, .net-6.0

I have a .NET6 project with minimal APIs. This is the code

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ClientContext>(opt => 
  opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("Clients"));
builder.Services
  .AddTransient<IClientRepository,
                ClientRepository>();
builder.Services
  .AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

var app = builder.Build();

// Get the Automapper, we can share this too
var mapper = app.Services.GetService<IMapper>();
if (mapper == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
      "Mapper not found");
}

app.MapPost("/clients",
  async (ClientModel model,
         IClientRepository repo) =>
  {
      try
      {
          var newClient = mapper.Map<Client>(model);
          repo.Add(newClient);
          if (await repo.SaveAll())
          {
              return Results.Created(
                $"/clients/{newClient.Id}",
                mapper.Map<ClientModel>(newClient));
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          logger.LogError(
            "Failed while creating client: {ex}",
            ex);
      }
      return Results.BadRequest(
        "Failed to create client");
  });
```

This code is working. I have a simple `Profile` for `AutoMapper`

```
public class ClientMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ClientMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Client, ClientModel>()
          .ForMember(c => c.Address1, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Address.Address1))
          .ForMember(c => c.Address2, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Address.Address2))
          .ForMember(c => c.Address3, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Address.Address3))
          .ForMember(c => c.CityTown, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Address.CityTown))
          .ForMember(c => c.PostalCode, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Address.PostalCode))
          .ForMember(c => c.Country, o => o.MapFrom(m => m.Address.Country))
          .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I wrote a `NUnit` test and a `xUnit` test. In both cases, when I call the API I receive the error

> Program: Error: Failed while creating client: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
> ClientModel -> Client
> MinimalApis.Models.ClientModel -> MinimalApis.Data.Entities.Client
> at lambda_method92(Closure , Object , Client , ResolutionContext )

How can I use the Profile in the main project? The full source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/Net6MinimalAPIs).

Comment: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` -> what is the entry assembly from a unit test project. Hint: it's not the project where the profiles are defined.

Comment: You are totally right. This is working in the API point of view. Do I have to add another one for the test projects?

Comment: I'd normally use `typeof(someClassInMyAssembly).Assembly` instead of `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`

Comment: Thank you so much @Llama It is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your project normally, `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` will resolve to your project's assembly (the one that contains the `Profile` classes). When you launch your project via a unit test project, the entry point is actually that unit test.

That means that this code isn't actually finding the profiles because they're not in that assembly:

```cs
builder.Services
  .AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
```

Normally what I do in this situation is to use `typeof(someAssemblyInMyProject).Assembly`. In this example I use `Program` but any class should work so long as its in the same project as the `Profile` classes:

```cs
builder.Services
  .AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program).Assembly);
```

Now, no matter what the entry assembly is, you'll still find the right list of profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate AutoMapper with a specific profile class using the code below:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(ClientMappingProfile));
var mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
```

To do this with dependency injection:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
{
    config.AddProfile(ClientMappingProfile);
});
```